# How to override implicits for types

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I have following problem, which is probably best showed as an example:

1) This code is provided in a library

```
sealed trait Base

class A extends Base
class B extends Base
class C extends Base

trait IntValue[T <: Base] {
  def value: Int
}

trait SomeApi {
  def apply[T <: Base : ClassTag]: Int
}

class ApiUsage(val api: SomeApi) {
  def someMethod() = {
    println(api[A])
    println(api[B])
    println(api[C])
  }
}
```

**SomeApi#apply** method should return Int value based on runtime type of **Base** trait. I know this example does not make sense, but I try to make it simple as much as possible. In real library this method return reference to an akka actor based on that type from actor system.

2) Now, I want to use **ApiUsage** class and provide values for types of **Base** trait via **implicit**, something like that:

```
object Test extends App {

  implicit val aValue = new IntValue[A] {
    def value: Int = 10
  }

  implicit val bValue = new IntValue[B] {
    def value: Int = 20
  }

  implicit def defaultValue[T <: Base : ClassTag] = new IntValue[T] {
    def value: Int = 30
  }

  private val api = new SomeApi {
    def apply[T <: Base : ClassTag]: Int = findValue[T]
  }

  private def findValue[T <: Base : IntValue : ClassTag] =    
    implicitly[IntValue[T]].value

  val apiUsage = new ApiUsage(api)

  apiUsage.someMethod()
}
```

What I want to do there is to create **ApiUsage** class and pass it reference to my local implementation of **SomeApi** which returns:
- 10 for **A** type
- 20 for **B** type
- 30 for other types (**C** in this case)

This test prints **30** in all cases.

Is there any way to elegantly solve this problem with implicits? Thanks very much

Comment: Is `SomeApi` something you can change? Because I don't think it works that way. You need to provide implicits for the whole call chain, otherwise compiler cannot infer that. You need `SomeApi { def apply[T <: Base : IntValue] }`

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't. But I can image if the signature would look like yours, then I will move implicits in ApiUsage scope and it will work

Comment: If I am correct and given that `implicitly` is written inside of the library, and there is no context bound - the implicits search is performed only locally inside the library, so you cannot provide your implicits implementations.

Comment: You can say it in another words - the implicits are resolved during compile time. And your library is already complied. So all the implicits are already resolved

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do without changing signatures is probably

```
val api = new SomeApi {
  def apply[T <: Base : ClassTag]: Int = {
    val clazz = classTag[T].runtimeClass
    if (clazz == classOf[A]) 
      10
    else if (clazz == classOf[B]) 
      20
    else 
      30
  }
}
```